# LIKE MySQL Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating a search engine with AJAX and a prepared statement. The search variables are sent and the AJAX query is successful, but the problem lies with my search query syntax. No matter how exact my search term is to my keywords, my num_rows is always 0. I am adding `% %` to search terms, I have tried deleting white space but I am out of ideas.

Examples of keywords are sad, acoustic, electric, blues etc.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$partialSearch = "%".$_POST['partialSearch']."%";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Name FROM videos WHERE Keywords LIKE ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$partialSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Name);

if($stmt->num_rows() == 0)
{
echo "No results found for ".$_POST['partialSearch'];
}else{
echo "Results for ".$_POST['partialSearch'];
echo $Name;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `echo $Name;` will not work especially when you receive more than one result.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($stmt->num_rows() == 0)
```

This is incorrect. [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) is a property, not a method. It should have been:

```
if($stmt->num_rows == 0)
```

I'd suggest enabling error reporting to discover silly errors like this. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) for more information on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a call to [`store_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) to get accurate count of records in the results:

Try:

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); // Add this line
$stmt->bind_result($Name);

if($stmt->num_rows == 0)
...
```